# Is there a macro for Windows 7 PowerPoint that will return a list of all hyperlinks in the presentation and their destinations?

Tags: windows-7, macros, hyperlink, powerpoint

I have searched and found solutions for older versions of PowerPoint but these don't work with the Windows 7 PowerPoint I have. I have a 200 page presentation with about 25 links on each slide which will take a long time to check individually. I need a way to see a list of each hyperlink and it's destination. All the links are to other pages in the PowerPoint.

Comment: show the code you have. It could be easier to find a problem than try to write a new code (which we usually don't do here).

Answer (score 0):

I have a commercial PowerPoint add-in that does various kinds of link repair and prep.  The free demo includes a link reporting tool that'll do exactly what you're asking for.

http://www.pptools.com/fixlinks/

No need to buy anything; the link report part is free with the demo; the demo is not time limited.

By the way, including that many links in a single presentation is asking for trouble. You'd be  better off breaking it up into multiple, interlinked presentation files.